# clearInterval() not working

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

```
<script>
var interval_time;

function executeQuery() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/get-session-timeout",
        success: function(jsonRes, textStatus, jqXmlHttpRequest) {
            console.log('success log session out');
            console.log(jqXmlHttpRequest.status);
        }

    });
    interval_time = setInterval(executeQuery, 30000);
}

function stopInterval() {
    console.log('stop interval hit');
    clearInterval(interval_time);
}
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    console.log('ready');
    interval_time = setInterval(executeQuery, 30000);

});
</script>



//FILE UPLOAD AJAX CALL

function uploadJqueryForm() {
    //logic
    $uploadFrm.ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            interval_time = setInterval(executeQuery, 30000);
            //logic
        },
        success: function(jsonRes) {
            stopInterval();
            //logic
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus,
            errorThrown) {
            stopInterval();
            //logic
        },
        complete: function(xhr, extStatus, errorThrown) {
            stopInterval();
        },
        dataType: "text"
    }).submit();
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Some more details would be nice, but maybe it's because setInterval is being called recursively?

Comment: i am doing file upload when it will start i want to update the session time out value in server side because its taking more time to upload(more than session time value which fixed in the server). So in every n sec. i am updating the session time out value in server side after upload i am unable to get session time out after n sec. stopInterval() hitting at last but again after that  repeatedly hitting success ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `setInterval()` in a variable which already has it without stoping it, you won't be able to clear it. So you should use `clearInterval()` and then `setInterval()` after it.

Answer (score 1):

You override `interval_time` many times. Then when you call `stopInterval()` only the last interval in `interval_time` will be stopped not the others.